# How can I prevent or diminish Nautilus freezing problems?

Tags: 10.04, nautilus

After upgrading the Ubuntu to 10.04 my Nautilus file manager gives lot of problem. Nautilus freezes after few minutes of start. I tried with Thunar, but I did not like that. Now I have Dolphin too, when Nautilus goes problem, then I start work with Dolphin. I do not like this. I want to work on Nautilus or equivalent one.

I work with lot of images using GIMP and Inkscape. I tried many things including reinstalled the OS for 6 time in 4 months. I cannot leave Ubuntu, but I am limbing. Some body help me to fix it.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Please phrase the title as a question!

Comment: Do you have any plugins for Nautilus installed? Are you using any network filesystems such as NFS or CIFS?

Answer (score 2):

You need to first diagnose your problem.

Try launching Nautilus from a Terminal by typing `nautilus` and pressing enter.
Any errors or warnings will be displayed in the terminal and this may help you to find the issue.

Your issue may already have been reported as a bug.
See Launchpad for a [list of bugs in nautilus](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nautilus).

Once a solution is found for one of these bugs, they will be fixed, but it may take a long time for the bug fixes to appear in Ubuntu. Often, however, people will post temporary solutions in the comments of a particular bug.

Also, [PCManFM](http://wiki.lxde.org/en/PCManFM) is another option for an alternative file manager. It is similar visually to nautilus, fast, but with a few less features.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to disable preview for images or other multi-media things. Such previews need memory as well as cpu power, which can lead to freezing when either the cpu is overloaded, or a lot of swapping occurs.